# Referencing cell value in formula vs cell address (for output like =FORMULATEXT()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I created a sheet that outlines what I'm looking for help on, would be so grateful for any help

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pTUgZnAJEnQy5pS3v5X8WrYGQFEwiuxcuk0Q5aC09zE/edit#gid=0

I basically want the output that =FORMULATEXT() gives but I want to reference the values inside the cell vs the cell address. What's the easiest way to do it?

Comment: the spreadsheet you provided is 1) blank 2) view-only. Can you enter some sample data and give edit rights?

Comment: This has simultaneously been asked [on another forum](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/145959561), so contributors here and there may want to check both in order not to duplicate efforts.

Answer (score 0):

> values inside the cell vs the cell address

'=substitute(substitute(FORMULATEXT(E7),"B7","value_1"),"B8","value_2")'

based on my understanding.. this is what you r looking for.. just replace FORMULATEXT() cell address for the next use..

Please share if it works/not/understandable. ( :